# Let f be a convex function on [a,b). Prove that f is bounded from below.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convex-analysis

Let $f$ be a [convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Definition) function on $[a,b)$. Prove that $f$ is bounded from below.

I don't know how to go about it. Applying the definition alone isn't leading anywhere. Can someone drop a hint as to how to begin solving this problem?

This is a problem from Real Analysis, H.L Royden, 3rd edition.

Comment: Hint: take two points of the graph of $f$ at abscissas $x_0< x_1$. Show that outside $[x_0, x_1]$, the graph of $f$ is above the line joining these two points.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $f:I\to \mathbb{R}$ is convex and interval $I$ is bounded, prove that $f$ is bounded below.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3112616/if-fi-to-mathbbr-is-convex-and-interval-i-is-bounded-prove-that-f-is)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $c=(a+b)/2$ and $d=(c+b)/2$. The definition of convexity implies that  in $[a,c]$,  the graph of $f$ lies weakly above the straight line $\ell$ connecting $(c,f(c))$ to $(d,f(d))$.

Indeed, if $(x,f(x))$ fell strictly below $\ell$  for some $x \in[a,c]$, then $(c,f(c))$ would be strictly above the line segment connecting $(x,f(x))$ to $(d,f(d))$.

Similarly, in $[c,b]$, the graph of $f$ lies weakly above the line connecting $(a,f(a))$ to $(c,f(c))$.

Comment: OK, I edited my answer.