# Prove if $f : (a,b) \to \Bbb R$ is a strictly decreasing convex function then it is bounded from below

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Prove if $f : (a,b) \to \Bbb R$ is a twice-differentiable, strictly decreasing convex function then $f$ is bounded from below.

I tried using the mean value theorem but I couldn't get any information about the behavior of $f$.

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3112616/42969.

Comment: That includes a closed interval, I'm talking about a strictly open interval.

Comment: No, $I$ can be any bounded interval. On unbounded intervals is the statement wrong.

Comment: Read carefully the link provided by Martin R

Comment: But what if $f$ is not bounded from above? Then the argument provided by the first answer doesn't hold. A convex function on an open interval doesn't have to be bounded from above.

Comment: If $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to a+$ look at $f$ on $[a+\epsilon, b)$.

Comment: The twice differentiable and strictly decreasing are unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

It is no loss of generality to assume that $f:[a',b)\to \mathbb R$ for some $a<a'<b$ and in fact that $a'=0$ and $f(a')=0.$ Then, for any $0<b'<b,\ f\ $ has a finite minimum on $[0,b']$ so if $f$ is not bounded below, then there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ increasing to $b$ such that $f(x_n)\to -\infty.$

Convexity of $f$ implies that for $x<y<z,$ if $\varphi(w) = \frac{f(w) - f(x)}{w - x}$ then $\varphi(y)\le \varphi(z).$ Applying this to our situation, we have $x=b'=f(b')=0$ so  $\varphi(w)=\frac{f(w)}{w}$ is increasing on $[0,b).$ But then $\varphi(x_n)$ is an increasing sequence with $\varphi(x_n)<0$ so it is bounded, at least eventually: there is an integer $N$ such that $\varphi(x_N)\neq 0.$ Then $\varphi(x_N)\le \varphi(x_n)\le 0$ as soon as $n\ge N.$ This is a contradiction because $f(x_n)\to -\infty$ and $x_n\to b.$

Comment: I am not *extending* $f$, rather restricting its domain from $(a,b)$ to a smaller subset of $(a,b).$ If $f$ is strictly decreasing on $(a,b)$ then if we choose an $a<a'<b$ if $f$ is bounded below on $[a', b)$ then it is also bounded below on $(a,b).$

Comment: I don't see how you get a contradiction. You have $f(x_{n+1}) \ge {x_{n+1} \over x_n} f(x_n)$, but since $f(x_n) <0$, you cannot immediately conclude that $f(x_{n+1}) >  f(x_n)$.

Comment: Convexity of $f$ implies that for $x<y<z,$ if $\varphi(w) = \frac{f(w) - f(x)}{w - x}$ then $\varphi(y)\le \varphi(z).$ Applying this to our situation, we have $x=b'=f(b')=0$ so  $\varphi(w)=\frac{f(w)}{w}$ is increasing on $[0,b).$ But then $\varphi(x_n)$ is an increasing sequence with $\varphi(x_n)<0$ so it is bounded, at least eventually: there is an integer $N$ such that $\varphi(x_N)\neq 0.$ Then $\varphi(x_N)\le \varphi(x_n)\le 0$ as soon as $n\ge N.$ This is a contradiction because $f(x_n)\to -\infty$ and $x_n\to b.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $c={1 \over 2} (a+b)$ below.

If $f$ is any real valued convex function on $(a,b)$ then it is bounded below. Pick any subgradient $g$ at $c$, then
$f(x)-f(c) \ge g(x-c) \ge -|g|{1 \over 2} (b-a)$.

**Alternative that does not involve subgradients:**

An important property of convex functions on the real line is that the secant function $R$ in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Functions_of_one_variable is symmetric and non decreasing as a function $x \mapsto R(x,x_2)$.

A little bit of work shows that
$g_+ = \lim_{h \downarrow 0} R(c,c+h)$ exists and since $g_+ \le R(c,x) =R(x,c)$, we have $f(x) - f(x) \ge g_+(x-c)$ for $c<x$.

Repeating shows that $g_- = \lim_{h \uparrow 0} R(c,c+h)$ exists (note that $h$ is negative) and as above we have
$R(c,x) = R(x,c) \le g_-$ for $x<c$ and this gives $f(x) - f(c) \ge g_-(x-c)$ for $x<c$.

The properties of $R$ show that $g_- \le g_+$. (As an aside, the elements of $[g_-,g_+]$ are the subgradients of $f$ at $c$.)

Combining these (and a little computation) shows that
$f(x) -f(c) \ge - \max(|g_-|,|g_+|){1 \over 2} (b-a)$ and hence $f$ is bounded below.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is more of an intuition than an answer. If $f(x)$ is a convex function in $(a,b)$, so it implies its first derivative is increasing, so $f''(x) \ge 0, x \in (a,b)$. But, we are also given that the function is strictly decreasing, meaning $f'(x)\le0, x \in (a,b)$. So, with a bit of thought (again note this is *not* a complete proof), for the function to remain convex yet decreasing in $(a,b)$ we can show that $$f''(x) \to 0$$ and $$f'(x) \to  0$$ so it is bounded from below. This is because the rate of change of the first derivative must decrease (yet not become negative otherwise function is concave) otherwise the first derivative will become positive (so the function becomes increasing).

Comment: didn't see that part, sorry

Comment: I'll make the edits now

Comment: @copper.hat are there any more faults now?

Comment: I don't know what limit you are referring to above.

Comment: I'm just trying to express that $f''(x)$ decreases but never becomes negative, and the first derivative increases but never becomes positive. Is there another better notation to represent this properly?